# Export logs from release stage to a git repo or some storage

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops, devops-services

I am creating a Azure Devops pipeline to build, test and export results for an ios application. After build->export artifacts-> In the release stage where I perform testing, I have trouble understanding exporting the logs and results.
I want to export the results (a zip file) from the Release Stage to either local or a .git repository.

```
(pipeline) Build IOS Application and Export Artifacts --> (Release Stage)Download Artifacts and Perform XCUITests & Export results
```

I tried writing a small script to upload the results to a git repo but it fails because it is impossible for me to add the ssh keygen generated to github for promptless authentication.

```
git clone https://madhukarbs@dev.azure.com/madhukarbs/Demo/_git/Test_Runs
git remote add origin https://madhukarbs@dev.azure.com/madhukarbs/Demo/_git/Test_Runs
git push -u origin --all
```

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://madhukarbs@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Do you have any better approach to make the results (Release Stage) in Azure DevOps Platform available over internet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be nice to have all under one ecosystem. So I uploaded the results to Azure Storage using the task azcopy.